# "F" no longer allowed in data.table fread NA

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I have a large csv that I am reading with fread.  Until recently, the na strings could include "F"  I updated to the latest version and that is no longer allowed.  How do I handle records with F in a numeric field? This is very common with Statistics Canada data.  The problem is found using r 3.5 with data table version 1.11.2.  Data table versions 1.10.4.3 does not object to the "F" in the NA string.

Here is a sample file

2010/01,Newfoundland and Labrador,,Used car dealers,"Unadjusted (x 1,000)",v52367418,2.5.1,F
2010/02,Newfoundland and Labrador,,Used car dealers,"Unadjusted (x 1,000)",v52367418,2.5.1,F
2010/03,Newfoundland and Labrador,,Used car dealers,"Unadjusted (x 1,000)",v52367418,2.5.1,F
2010/04,Newfoundland and Labrador,,Used car dealers,"Unadjusted (x 1,000)",v52367418,2.5.1,F
2010/05,Newfoundland and Labrador,,Used car dealers,"Unadjusted (x 1,000)",v52367418,2.5.1,11466.0

When I try to use fread() function on this file I get the following error:

```
 library(data.table)
 dt <- fread("data.csv", na.strings=c('F'))
#Error in fread("data.csv", na.strings = c("F")) :
#  freadMain: NAstring <<F>> is recognized as type boolean, this is not permitted.
```

Comment: I suppose the task of making a [MCVE] would be fairly simple, but it is your responsibility, not ours.

Comment: Could you file this as an issue on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues)? You should reference this SO Q&A and include the output of running `fread` with `verbose = TRUE`. Also FYI this outstanding FR would solve your issue automatically but it's not implemented yet: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2100

Answer (score 2):

I would just pre-process the input, or post-process the data.table.  For your example data, here is the second approach:

```
dt <- fread(txt)   ## with txt being your input data

dt[V8 != "F", V8new := as.numeric(V8)]   # convert numeric
dt[V8 == "F", V8new := NA]               # flag rest as NA
dt[, V8 := NULL]                         # delete old column
setnames(dt, "V8new", "V8")              # rename

dt
```

which gets me

```
R> dt[, 4:8]   ## more compact display
                 V4                   V5        V6    V7    V8
1: Used car dealers Unadjusted (x 1,000) v52367418 2.5.1    NA
2: Used car dealers Unadjusted (x 1,000) v52367418 2.5.1    NA
3: Used car dealers Unadjusted (x 1,000) v52367418 2.5.1    NA
4: Used car dealers Unadjusted (x 1,000) v52367418 2.5.1    NA
5: Used car dealers Unadjusted (x 1,000) v52367418 2.5.1 11466
R>
```

Comment: What I have done is switch modestly painfully to using read_csv which has other issues and is slower. and does process the "F" correctly  However, I will post in GIT hub